# The non-nullable local variable 'product ' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart

The non-nullable local variable 'product' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.
But the way I thought it ends up giving error

```
//product_model_test.dart

import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:app/models/product/product_model.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Test id', (tester) async {

    ProductModel product;
    print(product.id); //gives this error in product - The non-nullable local variable 'product' must be assigned before it can be used. Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.
  });
}

//product_model.dart

class ProductModel{
  ProductModel.fromWeb(Map data) {
    id = data['id'];
    description= data['description'];
    icon= data['icon'];
  }

  late final int id;
  late final String description;
  late final String? icon;
}
```

Comment: As the error says... `ProductModel product;` is just a variable declaration. `product` is not initialized at that point in time. Since you only provide one way to initialize (which is `ProductModel.fromWeb`), then you should call that: `ProductModel product = ProductModel.fromWeb(...);`

Comment: I inserted the Map() in fromWeb() -- it was like this ProductModel product = ProductModel.fromWeb(Map())

Comment: Ended up giving this error when running -> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'
new ProductModel.fromWeb
package:app/…/product/product_model.dart:3
main.<fn>
test\…\product\product_model_test.dart:8
2

✖ Test id

Comment: You're providing an empty map (`Map()` is an empty map), so when the constructor attempts to access data through `id = data["id"]`, it crashes; there is no associated value for the key "id" (because the map is empty). Therefore, you get `null` (which is the absence of a value) cannot be assigned to `int`, which is the type of value expected by `id`.

Comment: A map that works: `{"id": 1, "description": "Some description", icon: null }`.

Comment: I posted an answer to the question with an edit for this second error you had. Please vote it and mark it as the chosen answer if it helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main() {
  test('Test id', () {
    ProductModel product = ProductModel.fromWeb({{"id": 1, "description": "Some description", "icon": null }});
    print(product.id);
  });
}
```

In this way the error was solved

- Read the error comments, to understand better

Comment: Please read my answer as well. It may help you better understand what is happening, as well as, give you some tips on how to search for this behavior better in the future

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a value for `ProductModel product` before using it.

Like:

```dart
  ProductModel product = ProductModel.fromWeb(someMap);
```

If you want to tell dart that the variable hasn't been initialized yet and it may not have a `ProductModel` value when called, you should type it as:

```dart
  ProductModel? product;
  if (product != null) print(product!.id); // the "!" tells dart that you think this variable is not null here
```

Then if you want to use a parameter from a nullable class, you can do the following:

```dart
print(product?.id) //prints either the id or null
print(product?.id ?? 0) //prints either the id or (if the expression on the left is null) 0
```

This tells Dart that your variable can be `null`;
Or, if you ***know*** that this variable will never be null, but you'll assign it a value before using it, you can use the `late` modifier as in your class' parameters.

Dart is now a null-safe language so this `?` is how you tell a variable that it ***can*** be `null`

PS:
About your error on the comments above `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

The same applies to your inner variables. They should be `int?` if you are not sure that the given `Map` will give you the value for that `key`. Or you could do something like:

```dart
class ProductModel{
  ProductModel.fromWeb(Map data) {
    id = data['id'] ?? 0; //will automatically set the value to 0 if the map didn't have that key or the value for it was null
    description= data['description'] ?? ''; //will automatically set the value to '' if the map didn't have that key or the value for it was null
    icon= data['icon'];
  }

  final int id;
  final String description;
  final String? icon;
}
```